# Check at compile-time if an uninstantiated class template inherits from its first template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-templates

### Short question

How could I check at compile-time if a (**edit:** uninstantiated) class template inherits from its first template parameter as of C++17?

### Long question

I want to find out if a class template inherits from its (first) template parameter, by constructing something along the lines of:

```
template<template<typename> class TemplateClass>
struct template_parameter_is_base_of
{
    /* Implementation */
};
```

Ideally, `template_parameter_is_base_of` could be used like this:

```
template<typename T> struct WithParent : T { /* Implementation */ };
template<typename T> struct WoutParent :   { /* Implementation */ };

static_assert(template_parameter_is_base_of<WithParent>::value); // Ok as expected since WithParent inherits from T
static_assert(template_parameter_is_base_of<WoutParent>::value); // Error as expected since WithParent doesn't inherit from T
```

#### My failed attempt

My attempt to implement `template_parameter_is_base_of`:

```
struct Dummy {};

template<template<typename> class TemplateClass>
struct template_parameter_is_base_of
{
    static constexpr bool value = std::is_base_of_v<Dummy, TemplateClass<Dummy>>;
};
```

... which works in this case:

```
template<typename T>
struct A : T {
    void work() { /* Irrelevant implementation */ }
};

static_assert(template_parameter_is_base_of<A>::value); // Passes because A inherits from its template parameter. Nice!
```

... but it fails if a class template has a method with the `override` specifier:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct B : T {
    void work() override { /* Irrelevant implementation */ }
};

static_assert(template_parameter_is_base_of<B>::value); // Fails, but I want it to pass because B inherits from its template parameter.
```

#### This is what I think right now

I think I have painted myself into a corner with the `Dummy` approach used above, since the class template instantiation of `TemplateClass<Dummy>` within `std::is_base_of_v` will always fail if `TemplateClass` contains any methods with the `override` specifier.

However, I think that implementing `template_parameter_is_base_of` *should be possible* because a compiler *should* know at compile-time whether a class template inherits from its template parameter or not. Maybe I am mistaken.

#### Finally the question

Is it possible to implement `template_parameter_is_base_of` as of C++17? If yes, how could that be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, I think that implementing `template_parameter_is_base_of` *should be possible* because a compiler *should* know at compile-time whether a template class inherits from its template parameter or not.

A template is essentially a parameterized tool for manufacturing certain C++ constructs: class, function, or variable. A template, in and of itself, is not yet the thing it will make. A class template does not inherit from anything because it is *not a class yet*. So the question itself is not a functional one.

Coupled with that is the fact that explicit/partial template specialization exists. Even if the base class template did indeed inherit from its first template parameter, that's no guarantee of anything. You still have no idea if any particular `WithParent<T>` instantiation of the template will actually use the base template. A user could easily specialize `WithParent` for a particular type, or even employ partial specialization for a whole family of types.

What you want is not a thing C++ can support. If you're trying to verify something or prevent certain misuse or whatever, you're going to have to do it another way.

Comment: *A user could easily specialize WithParent for a particular type, or even employ partial specialization for a whole family of types.*

Aha, this made me understand your answer. I can not know at compile-time if the class template really ended up with inheriting from its template parameter, because a class template is in a sense not "definitive" since a specialization of the class template might as well not inherit from T... Thank you.

Comment: This is my usual reason for deeming CTAD (as useful as it can be) voodoo: it examines the constructors of a class *template* which, not being a class, ought not have any.  We can of course broaden our definition of “constructor”, but I don’t know all the consequences of such a move.

Comment: @davis it examines the deduxtion guides of a class template, which can in turn be synthesized from a class template.

Comment: @DavisHerring: There's no "voodoo"; a primary template is a well-defined construct in C++. The implicit deduction guides are simply manufactured from the primary class template. The stuff in a template definition does in fact exist and does in fact represent legit C++ code, so looking at some of that code is perfectly valid. CTAD does not promise that primary class template constructors *will be called*; it merely uses them to figure out how to deduce template arguments.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Of course the declarations in a (primary) class template exist, but it’s not clear (to me?) what it is that they declare (even `using V=void;` in such a context isn’t *a* type alias, but a plan for some number of them).  It’s not even clear that a primary template is an entity, since one can argue that it is the primary along with all its partial/explicit specializations that is “the class template”.

Comment: @DavisHerring: And yet, if you put `using V = something_that_isnt_a_typename;`, the compiler will complain. What you put into a template has to be at least potentially legitimate C++. "*It’s not even clear that a primary template is an entity*" Does it matter if it is or isn't? A primary template is a construct that definitely exists. It is the term for a specific construct which is grammatically distinct from non-primary templates. Therefore, you can identify "the primary template for the template entity X".

Comment: @NicolBolas: It matters for the usual reason that other things [depend on its status](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#12.sentence-2).  This is often, fortunately, more a matter for the committee than for the user.

Answer (score 1):

> How could I check at compile-time if a class template inherits from its first template parameter as of C++17?

You mean, if an *instantiated* class template inherits from its first template parameter?

Simple, use [`std::is_base_of_v`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of):

```
template <typename T, /*other stuff goes here*/>
class A : /* classes which A inherits from */ { /* ... */}

template <typename T, /*other stuff goes here*/>
constexpr bool A_inherits_its_first_tempalte_param() {
    return std::is_base_of_v<T, A<T, /* ... */ >;
}
```

that's it.

Comment: No, I really meant an uninstantiated class template. I have updated the question to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure is a good one, but I propose you the following way to explore.

You can try writing a type traits as follows

```
template <typename T>
void foo (T *);

template <template <typename> class, typename = void>
struct tp_is_base_of : public std::false_type
 { };

template <template <typename> class C>
struct tp_is_base_of<
   C, std::void_t<decltype(foo<Dummy>(std::declval<C<Dummy>*>()))>>
     : public std::true_type
 { };
```

This way you check if a `C<Dummy>` pointer is accepted by a function that waits for a `Dummy` pointer: if `C<Dummy>` inherit from `Dummy`, the answer should be yes.

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <type_traits>

struct Dummy { virtual void work() {} };

template <typename T>
struct A : T
 { void work() { /* Irrelevant implementation */ } };

template <typename T>
struct B : T
 { void work() override { /* Irrelevant implementation */ } };

template <typename T>
struct C
 { };

template <typename T>
void foo (T *);

template <template <typename> class, typename = void>
struct tp_is_base_of : public std::false_type
 { };

template <template <typename> class C>
struct tp_is_base_of<
   C, std::void_t<decltype(foo<Dummy>(std::declval<C<Dummy>*>()))>>
     : public std::true_type
 { };

int main()
 {
   static_assert( true  == tp_is_base_of<A>::value );
   static_assert( true  == tp_is_base_of<B>::value );
   static_assert( false == tp_is_base_of<C>::value );
 }
```